# Xml foreach loop with lots of records, limit records pulled by category and number

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach

```
$feed = 'myfeed';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach( $xml->productinfo as $productinfo )
{
$product_category = $productinfo->category;
$product_description = $productinfo->description;

now i inserv each product categor and description into my table.
}
```

I'm storing the products data, category and description in my database.

**Problem is the feed has about 5000 products, in 10 categories. I don't neet to get hundreds of products for each category, I just need about 50. How can I limit the foreach loop, so when for example it loops through 50 tv's, stops and loops through 50 microwaves... and so on.**

Any ideeas?

Ty!

Comment: use [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)  instead?

Comment: It's complicated, lets say the feed has 200 tvs, 500 cellphones, 400 remotes. I need to get inside my database just 50 tvs, 50 cells and 50 remotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,if i unserstood it correct you need something like this :

```
$feed = 'myfeed';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach( $xml->productinfo as $productinfo )
{
  $product_category = $productinfo->category;
  $$product_category++;
  if($$product_category>50) continue;
  $product_description = $productinfo->description;

//now i inserv each product categor and description into my table.
}
```

so if you have a product_category lets say tv :

```
$product_category='tv';
$$product_category=$tv;
```

and if you have a product_category lets say microwave :

```
$product_category='microwave';
$$product_category=$microwave;
```

Comment: ys, but the xml is linear, i mean first the 200 tvs, and than the 500 microwaves... your solution would just give me for example 50 tvs, than another 50. If for example I'd have 4 cats it would not reach the second one, microwaves. Hope you understood what i ment, hard to explain

Comment: erm,all of the products are in the same xml right?thats what i understood...if thats the case the code above would work...see my edit you might understand what i try to do..unless each category is in a different xml??:S

Comment: It's in the same xml, you are a genious;)

Comment: Could you edit it completly, I want to understand where to put the xml exactly

Comment: can you be more specific on what you didn't understand?i cant give you more code if i don't have the xml unfortunately